# Changing dynamically a layout with php and handlebars based on foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, key, handlebarshelper

Here's my problem:

```
<?php
$handlebars->registerHelper('cols', function ($var, $args) use ($handlebars) {
    $cols = 0;

    if (is_array($var) && count($var) == 2) {
        $cols = 6;
    }
    if (is_array($var) && count($var) == 4) {
        $cols = 3;
    }
    if (is_array($var) && count($var) == 3) {
        $cols = 4;
    }
    if (is_array($var) && count($var) > 4) {
        foreach ($var as $key => $data) {

            if ($key > 3) {
                echo $key;
                $cols = 4;
                //return $cols;
            } else {
                echo $key;
                $cols = 6;
                //return $cols;
            }

        }
    }
    return $cols;
});


{{#each cards}}
<div class="col-lg-{{#cols cards}} mb-4 {{#if centered}}text-center{{/if}} {{#if threedee}}raised-card{{/if}} basic-card">
    

</div>
{{/each}}
```

I'm trying to dynamically generate a layout, based on the number of items that live in a database.

Let's assume (just to avoid writing a ton of code) that each function works (I'm using lazyblock  on WordPress and which works with handlebar - a mix of PHP and mustache).

I want to change the number of the column based on the number of the items of a particular category in the DB, then I loop through them and I finally, depends on the number of the total amount of items, I will create my layout.

So far so good, except for the fact that, if I have 5 items I want to print two different number (for two different bootstrap columns) 4 for the first three columns and 6 for the remaining 2.

The problem is that, if I echo the key, like in the mentioned code I obtained those values: 01234, so I would be able to assign two different value:

```
if ($key > 3) {
    echo $key;
    $cols = 4;
    //return $cols;
} else {
    echo $key;
    $cols = 6;
    //return $cols;
}
```

but if I return the value instead, the total is different, the if statement won't work.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you understand what `return` does? It will end the function execution. Meaning, it would immediately return `6`, since the first key is `0`, which is less than `3`. On the other hand, when you don't return, the loop will keep overwriting `$cols` and ultimately have the value of `6` (you have shown that `4` is the final key). So overall, both those cases don't make sense; the option with returning depends only on the first key and the one without depends only on the last key, making the loop unnecessary. Seems like you need to return an array?

Comment: @El_Vanja, yes, set up the $cols = 0 differently first, like $cols = [], but then how I can return that array. plus I'm working with handlebars php which makes my life hader

Comment: What do you suggest to tackle the problem?  @El_Vanja

Comment: And mainly, how can I get the key index without looping the object?

Comment: I have no idea how you're calling this or what the return value should actually be, so it's difficult to come up with a concrete solution. But I feel like you should be looping inside your template, not here. And then send the key from the template as a second parameter which you would use to determine the value to be returned when `count($var) > 4`.

Comment: I'm already looping in my template.. I will try to follow your suggestion somehow, it is kind of complicate the entire framework I guess